# how to get Custom native query string Value from JPA repository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have written some custom native queries in my custom JPA repository using @Query annotations. As per my requirement I need to get the query from repository and print it to log file ( to know which query executed in run time). I know those queries are inside query cache as key value pair. How to get the query string from repository?

Thanks.

Comment: If your purpose is to log the queries, then enable hibernate query logging (logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL), which will log all the query in the runtime.

Comment: @RatulSharker I want to write into log file

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can use Log4j to log to file. Example: .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="WARN">
  <appenders>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>             
  </appenders>

  <loggers>     
    <root level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="MyFile" level="error"/>
    </root>    
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

You totally can customize your xml file in many ways

- Filter what logs you want to write to file. In your case, it is logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL
- Log levels
- Log Patterns
- ...